# Using colors defined in base module from feature module fails after rebuilding the Android Instant App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, android-instant-apps

I have a `base` module and a feature module called `query` module in my Instant App project.

My `QueryActivity` inside `query` module uses colors that are in `base` module.

[QueryActivity.kt](https://github.com/mustafaberkaymutlu/uv-index/blob/master/query/src/main/java/net/epictimes/uvindex/query/QueryActivity.kt#L130-L135):

```
@ColorInt
val textColor: Int = when (resultCode) {
    FetchAddressIntentService.RESULT_SUCCESS -> android.R.color.white
    FetchAddressIntentService.RESULT_FAILURE -> R.color.accent // this color is inside the base module
    else -> R.color.accent // this color is inside the base module
}
```

If I try to `run` the project, it works fine without any problem. But If I `rebuild` the project, it gives me the following error:

```
../net/epictimes/uvindex/query/QueryActivity.kt
Error:(133, 63) Unresolved reference: color
Error:(134, 27) Unresolved reference: color
```

Pointing to those color values.

I solved this by I adding another `colors.xml` file inside the `query` module and referencing the `base` colors from it. It worked fine. You can see the diff in [this commit](https://github.com/mustafaberkaymutlu/uv-index/commit/be051af35b2edf4d3e3c6889a86e8d9258f48e75).

```
<color name="query_location_success_text">@android:color/white</color>
<color name="query_location_fail_text">@color/accent</color>
```

Right now it works but I am not sure why. Is this the right way to do it? My question is shouldn't be the resources inside `base` module accessible from the feature modules?

Versions:

> Android target/compile SDK: 26
>
> Kotlin: 1.1.50
>
> Instant Apps: 1.1.0

That is a open source project of mine, you can see whole project [here](https://github.com/mustafaberkaymutlu/uv-index).

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, resource inside base module is accessible from the feature modules when you reference it with the fully qualified name (package_name.R.resource_name).

Base and child modules have different package names (your base feature package name is `net.epictimes.uvindex`, and your feature module package name is `net.epictimes.uvindex.query`).

Each package contains its own set of resources, and their resource IDs are collected in separate R packages during compilation:

- `net.epictimes.uvindex.R` - for your base feature module
- `net.epictimes.uvindex.query.R` - for your feature module

To access an ‘accent’ color resource of a base feature from your ‘query’ feature module, use `net.epictimes.uvindex.R.color.accent` identifier:

> FetchAddressIntentService.RESULT_FAILURE -> net.epictimes.uvindex.R.color.accent

Comment: The resource management with instant apps is at this moment completely flawed. It is currently an unworkable piece of ...
Lint is not complaining about wrongly used R.x statements.   
In many cases resources are only available from the base module. 
using <include> inside a feature module will break everything if the include is supposed to be fetched from the base module.
And we haven't talked about the complete destruction when you use proguard which is not able to detect cross dependencies between modules.

Comment: You are right. Each module generates its own R.java and the problem here is I was referencing the wrong R file. Thank you for your help. But I think its weird that "run" works fine but "rebuild" fails with the unresolved reference error.